# Find the gradient of the curve?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Find the gradient of the curve $y=\frac{2x-4}{x^2}$ at the point where the curve crosses the axis.

I did it 
$y=\frac{2}{2x}$ 
 but the right answer is $\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point where the curve crosses the axis is $(2,0)$.

To find the gradient, you need to find the first derivative of the function:

$$y'=\frac{2x^2-2x(2x-4)}{x^4}\tag{1}$$

And all you should do is calculating $y'$ when $x=2$:

$$(1)\stackrel{\text{(2,y')}}{\implies} y'=\frac{1}{2}$$

---

Your derivative is wrong, Using [the quotient rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule), you'll have:

$$y' = \frac{(2x-4)' \cdot x^2 - (x^2)' \cdot (2x-4)}{{(x^2)}^2}$$

$$ = \frac{2 \cdot x^2 - 2x \cdot (2x-4)}{x^4}$$

$$ = \frac{-2x^2 +8x }{x^4}$$
$$= \frac{-2x+8}{x^3}\tag{2}$$

$$(2)\stackrel{\text{x=2}}{\implies}\frac{-2 \cdot 2+8}{2^3}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: why not derivative is $y=\frac{2}{2x}$  and 
how did it into $y'=\frac{2x^2-2x(2x-4)}{x^4}$ can u explain? thx

Comment: @SbSangpi: Did you use the [quotient rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule)? You don't need to simplify it since you will set $x=2$. It's wrong, try again using the rule and you'l go fine.

Comment: $\frac{-2x+8}{x^3}$ shouldn't be $\frac{-2x+8}{4x^3}$ or u cancel by $x$? thx alot.

Comment: @SbSangpi: Yes, an $x$ in the numerator with an $x$ in the denominator.

Answer (score 1):

The gradient at a specific point is a fixed vector, while the gradient function is a function of the independent variables. So therefore you have to compute the gradient at the specific point. In this case the point where the curve crosses the axis, so (2,0). So therefore $\nabla y|_{x=2}=\frac{-2x+8}{x^3}\vec{i}|_{x=2}=\frac{1}{2}\vec{i}$

Answer (score 1):

Note that, in general,
$$
\left(\frac{u}{v}\right)'\not=\frac{u'}{v'}
$$
When taking the derivative of a quotient, the rule is
$$
\left(\frac{u}{v}\right)'=\frac{u'v-uv'}{v^2}
$$
which, as pointed out in other posts, is
$$
\frac{2\cdot x^2-(2x-4)\cdot2x}{x^4}=\frac{8-2x}{x^3}
$$